# How to show message date in JSQMessagesViewController

Tags: ios, swift, date, chat, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am trying to make a chat app and I am using JSQMessagesViewController library.
My Chat View show all the messages with their date and time but I am facing some little bit of problem with this library.
My problem is I wanna show message date only Once.
Suppose:
Yesterday date contains 10 messages
and today date contains 15 messages

and I wanna show Only single date of these messages as not repeat dates for every messages [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you need to determine if the message is the first of that day. Then return nil for all the others till a new day.

I created a function to determine if my message was the first sent by that individual. It looks like this

```
func firstMessageOfTheDay(indexOfMessage: NSIndexPath) -> Bool { 
  let messageDate = messages[indexOfMessage.item].date
  guard let previouseMessageDate = messages[indexOfMessage.item - 1].date else {
    return true // because there is no previous message so we need to show the date
  }
    let day = Calendar.current.component(.day, from: messageDate)
    let previouseDay = Calendar.current.component(.day, from: previouseMessageDate)
    if day == previouseDay {
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```

Then call that in the appropriate function.  Hope that helps let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Thanks Daniel its really perfect answer that i need

Comment: I'm glad it helped

Comment: Hi Umesh, can you post your whole code for display date please? I can't find the way to do it like you

Answer (score 1):

Use this method to do this.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView, attributedTextForCellTopLabelAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSAttributedString? {
```

You have to check the message date if the date is different then previous message date return date in which format you want otherwise return nil.

Comment: @DilipTiwari how i can help you ?

Comment: you should check order of incoming messages.

Comment: this is my code bro https://gist.github.com/diliptiwari333/c4590979d6b5086d85090e19c77b8313

Comment: Bro you need to understand async operations. At the line 153 you downloading image after that you are adding that to messages list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177068/discussion-between-dilip-tiwari-and-commando24).